# AWS Cloud formation output templates

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a CFT template created and every time when i execute cloud formation , I should receive 5 different user names in output

Example

```
Output

1st attempt - test-drive-01@example.com
2nd attempt - test-drive-02@example.com
upto 5 attempts - test-derive05@example.com

Again on 6th attempt it should go back to test-drive-01@example.com

"Outputs" : {
      "Username" : {
       "Description" : "Appcito Cafe UserName",
       "Value" :  { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "testdrive-[dynamic(01-05)]@example.com"]]}
      },
```

Can anyone please help with the sample template output.

Comment: What does "execute cloud formation" mean here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of CloudFormation having anything built in to support cycling values based on existing values. You have a few choices to solve this:

1. Pass the email address (or just the prefix) in as a parameter on each call
2. Create a custom resource that has this logic in it. You can use Lambda function that can easily cycle these values based on the current value for the template. [See more information on custom resources.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html) You should be able to pass the existing value in the template into this function to get it to iterate to the next value and pass it back.